# Getting IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-redux, stripe-payments

I am following a Amazon clone guide to get me started with React JS. While being 4 days in im getting stuck after processing my Orders. I am using Stripe, Firebase, Axios and Express to do this. After clicking the Buy now button im getting the error:

Tried every possible solution and the videoguide doesnt get this error or discuss this error in anyway.

Thanks in advance!

I wouldnt mind sharing my github so your getting a full look at all my codes if need be.

This is my payment page code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Checkout from './Checkout';
import './Payment.css'
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';
import CheckoutProduct from './CheckoutProduct';
import {  Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import CurrencyFormat from 'react-currency-format';
import { getBasketTotal } from './reducer';
import axios from './axios';



function Payment() {
  const [{ basket, user}, dispatch] = useStateValue(); 
  const history = useHistory();

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
       //generate the special stripe secret which allows us to charge a customer 

       const getClientSecret = async () => {
            const response = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                //Stripe expects the total in a currencies subunits
                url: "/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}" // Currency subunit
            });
            setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)
       }

       getClientSecret();
  }, [basket])

  console.log('THE SECRET IS >>>', clientSecret)

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
      //do all the fancy stripe stuff...
      event.preventDefault();
      setProcessing(true);

      const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
          payment_method: {
              card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
          }
      }).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
          //paymentIntent = payment confirmation

          setSucceeded(true);
          setError(null)
          setProcessing(false)

          history.replace('/orders')
      })
  }

  const handleChange = event => {
      //Listen for changes in the CardElement
      //and display any errors as the customer types their card details
      setDisabled(event.empty);
      setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
  }

  return (
    <div className='payment'>
       <div className='payment_container'>
           <h1>
               Checkout (
                   <Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} items</Link>
                   )
           </h1>

           {/* Payment section - delivery address */}
           <div className='payment_section'>
                <div className='payment_title'>
                    <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
                </div>
                <div className='payment_address'>
                    <p>{user?.email}</p>
                    <p>123 K.N Katju Marg</p>
                    <p>Rohini, New Delhi</p>
                </div>
            </div>

           {/* Payment section - Review Items */}
           <div className='payment_section'>
               <div className='payment_title'>
                   <h3>Review items and delivery</h3>
               </div>
               <div className='payment_items'>
                   {basket.map(item => (
                       <CheckoutProduct
                           id={item.id}
                           title={item.title}
                           image={item.image}
                           price={item.price}
                           rating={item.rating}
                        />   
                   ))}
               </div>
            </div>

           {/* Payment section - Payment method */}
           <div className='payment_section'>
               <div className='payment_title'>
                   <h3>Payment Method</h3>
               </div>
               <div className='payment_details'>
                     {/* Stripe magic will go*/}

                     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                         <CardElement onChange={handleChange}/>

                         <div className='payment_priceContainer'>
                             <CurrencyFormat
                             renderText={(value) => (
                                 <>
                                 <h3>Order Total: {value}</h3>
                                 </>
                             )}
                             decimalScale={2}
                             value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                             displayType={"text"}
                             thousandSeparator={true}
                             prefix={"$"}
                            />
                            <button disabled={processing || disabled || 
                            succeeded}>
                                <span>{processing ? <p>Processing</p> :
                                "Buy Now"}</span>
                            </button>
                         </div>

                         {/* Error */}
                        {error && <div>{error}</div>} 
                     </form>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default Payment
```

This is my index.js code or my server:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

// API

// - App config
const app = express();

// - Middlewares
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// - API routes
app.get('/', (request, response) => response.status(200).send('hello world'))

app.post('/payments/create', async (request, response) => {
    const total = request.query.total;

    console.log('Payment Request Recieved for this amount >>> ', total);

    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: total,     //Subunits of the currency
        currency: "usd",
    });

    // OK - Created
    response.status(201).send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    })
})

// - Listen command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

This is my axios.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://xxx/xxx"  
    // The API (cloud function) URL
});

export default instance;
```

Now this is the error I am getting always.
enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jiMJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

based on the console error message. You are passing boolean true to `stripe.confirmCardPayment()`, instead you should pass the PaymentIntent's `client_secret` to it.

I'd suggest you to debug around the backend code and make sure it return a valid `client_secret` to your frontend.

Comment: Please can you elaborate what you want to tell.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace " " form const response = await {url:"this one"} to   this.
For this press key which is left side of your keyboard 1.
Since inside URL we are using the js variable getBasket so we need to use ``